# Get a long array from an xml resource in Android program

Tags: android, arrays, xml

In order to build vibrate pattern, I tried to define the array of data, in XML.

```
<string-array name="tab_bip_1">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>100</item>
    <item>100</item>
</string-array>

    Resources r = getResources();
    long[]tab_vibrate = r.getIntArray(R.array.tab_bip_1); // Not correct...
    Vib.vibrate(tab_vibrate, 0);
```

But to get array of values, it seems to be only possible to use getIntArray() which give an Int array, when vibrate needs a long array.
Is there a kind of "getLongArray()" method?
Or do I have to get data in string then loop to perform a long.parseLong() against each value?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to manually copy a `long[]` to `int[]` :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<string-array name="tab_bip_1">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>100</item>
    <item>100</item>
</string-array>
```

You're trying to get IntArray, but this is a string array. Try this:

```
<integer-array name="tab_bip_1">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>100</item>
    <item>100</item>
</integer-array>
```

And replace `long` with `int`, because it is just integer array.

Answer (score 0):

Other than `string` resource we have in Android, we have the followings: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html

As you can see, there is not `long` type of xml resource. You need to use `integer` for number-type resources.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. Using an int array may be sufficient in this case but at the end I need to convert values as Vibrate don't want an Int Array but a Long one. :(

Also, using and Int array in XML is OK only if you have value lower than 32 bits. Not sure of what getIntArray() will say if we have an XML file with values greater than 32 bits.

I resolved my problem looping and casting string to long like this:

```
 <string-array name="tab_bip_1">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1000</item>
    <item>2000</item>
</string-array>


    // Get vibration array, which is in String
    Resources r = getResources();
    String[]str_tab_vibrate = r.getStringArray(R.array.tab_bip_1);

    // Then loop around to transforme in long values
    long[] long_tab_vibrate = new long[str_tab_vibrate.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < str_tab_vibrate.length; i++) {
        long_tab_vibrate[i] = Long.parseLong(str_tab_vibrate[i]);
    }

   // Then, vibrate
    Vibrator Vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    Vib.vibrate(long_tab_vibrate, 0);
```

It works. Hope this will help.